# Open online document with Google Docs

Tags: java, google-api

Does Google provides any API for open the online document(.docx) with Google Docs? if yes any materials that I can refer to? My idea is client can upload the document to the website then it can open and edit it by using Google Docs instead of download it and open with installed software.

Answer (score 0):

Google drive has a REST API
[the article on their site](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk)

You will be able to upload / edit files from the user and the user will be able to open them but I don't know if you can force open a document.

And if you use this API it would require the user  to login in which may or may not be something you want.

Or you could have a look at google picker (found om the same link)

Create and open files using the Google Picker

> Drive files can be opened from an application independently of the
>   Drive UI. An application can easily fetch and display a list of files
>   with the Google Picker as described in Open files using the Google
>   Picker.

Anyway: Do some more research on their site, you will probably get it done with Google Picker